# how to receive SMS via python-gsmmodem

Tags: python, linux, sms, gsm

I'm a newbie to python. I have installed [python-gsmmodem](https://github.com/faucamp/python-gsmmodem) in Ubuntu 14.04 to send and receive sms via a GSM dongle. Then in my `/usr/local/bin`  folder there were 3 scripts named

1. **`gsmterm.py`**
2. **`identify-modem.py`**
3. **`sendsms.py`**

I used those scripts successfully to send SMS,identify-modem as they implied by their name.

But the ***problem is*** I want to receive SMS via the dongle and can't figure out how to do it.When I download the whole package as a zip file there are some scripts that shows do sending SMS.

Apart from that doc of **python-gsmmodem** says it has functions to handle most of the functionality in a GSM modem including sending SMS.

Need help me on receiving SMS using the same modem. How to go about this problem ?

Comment: Have you looked at [examples/sms_handler_demo.py](https://github.com/faucamp/python-gsmmodem/blob/master/examples/sms_handler_demo.py) from your supplied GitHub link? It seems to implement receiving SMS messages.

Comment: yeah..it's works and seems to be waiting until a message is received. but it doesn’t show the message received. So i have made some changes in it such as port and baud rate according to my modem. still it have the same problem.then i have figured out that it sets message storage mode to dongle storage( AT+CPMS="ME" ) but the receiving messages are storing in the SIM card. So I'm  searching for a way to change the storage mode to SIM card(AT+CPMS="SM" ).@Pit

Comment: Have you tried setting the storage mode yourself (i.e. `modem.write("AT+CPMS=SM")`)?

Comment: yes.. I tried to do that and it was unsuccessful.

Comment: Which GSM modem are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a few examples in `tools/` and `examples/` in the [python-gsmmodem](https://github.com/faucamp/python-gsmmodem) repo. There is a script `examples/sms_handler_demo.py` that listens for incoming SMS messages and replies to the SMS by saying Thank you.

I've tried that script and it's waiting for SMS infinitely – SMS messages are received and placed into the selected storage by modem in the background, but the script doesn't catch any sms notification from modem and the reply callback isn't executed. It seems my Huawei modem needs a different setting for AT+CNMI command, or needs a proprietary set of commands.

EDIT: I've found the issue. I have a Huawei E372 modem, which creates 3 serial ports

- `/dev/ttyUSB0` - full AT command set, only query/response terminal, no notifications
- `/dev/ttyUSB1` - ? (not needed anyway)
- `/dev/ttyUSB2` - full AT command set, query/response console including receiving status messages like `^BOOT`, `^RSSI`, `^CSNR`, call notifications (`^RING`), SMS notifications (`^CMTI`, `^CDSI`) and USSD notifications (`^CUSD`)

In the beginning, I couldn't connect to `/dev/ttyUSB1` and `/dev/ttyUSB2` with python so I used `/dev/ttyUSB0`. The script was waiting infinitely because there are no notifications on the `/dev/ttyUSB0` port.
I found out that I couldn't connect to `/dev/ttyUSB2` with python "BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe" because of a bug in `pyserial 3.0.1`, so make sure you've installed the latest `3.1a0` version from git.

Now it works out of the box for me.

---

Make sure that

- you're using fixed pyserial module (v2.7, or v3.1a0+)
- you're using the correct serial port
- notifications are visible with serial console (`screen /dev/ttyUSB2 115200`, or `python tools/gsmterm.py -b 115200 /dev/ttyUSB2`)